# On Kelley's _General Topology_ Set Theory

Tags: set-theory

This question asks about the Set Theory summarized in the appendix of Kelley's book [*General Topology*](https://archive.org/details/GeneralTopology).

Is it equivalent to some of the [MK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morse%E2%80%93Kelley_set_theory), [NBG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Bernays%E2%80%93G%C3%B6del_set_theory) or [ZFC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory) set theories? Or is it different (maybe partial equivalent, ''embedded'')?

Direct link to page: https://archive.org/stream/GeneralTopology/Kelley-GeneralTopology#page/n267/mode/2up

> The system of axioms adopted is a variant of systems of Skolem and of A. P. Morse and owes much to the Hilbert-Bernays-von Neumann system as formulated by Godel. The formulation used here is designed to give quickly and naturally a foundation for mathematics which is free from the more obvious paradoxes.

Comment: Without having seen the book, usually in texts such as these the set theory is informal (i.e. done without axioms). If one looks at the implicit assumptions, however, they're often $ZF$ or $ZFC$

Comment: Kelley is the "K" in MK, so I imagine it'll be closely related.

Comment: Where has yellow comment of my question appeared from???  :0 It is a good answer (even Eric's is more clear for me).

Comment: @Malice: Yes I know both KELLEY's (sorry, I've written_Kelly_ many times) are the same person, but the axioms are different, at least different from Wikipedia's. So I thought maybe it was a '' short '' theory.

Comment: So you know the Wikipedia page for MK, but you don't see that in the second paragraph they mention this very book?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I promise. I don't usually read the preamble of Wikipedia pages. This shows me that is a bad idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This system is exactly MK.  Indeed, MK stands for Morse-*Kelley*, and this appendix is one of the places that MK set theory was originally formulated (and is the reason it is named after Kelley).